# subtract leftskip from textwidth inside a expression

Tags: calculations, resize

If I do: `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth-\leftskip]{image.png}`

I don't get the same picture size as if I subtract its values of 483pt-60pt = 423pt.

But if i do: `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth-10em]{image.png}`

the image gets smaller...

How can i subtract `\leftskip` from `\textwidth` inside the width preamble of the graphic expression?

Here is my someway complicated MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[
    left=20mm,
    right=20mm,
    top=20mm,
    bottom=18mm,
    footskip=2em,
    headheight=2em,
    headsep=0.8em
    ]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}   
    \usepackage{lipsum} 
    \leftskip=60pt                      
    \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}      
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}             
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      \setlength{\textwidth}{483pt}         
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\section}
       {\normalfont\fontsize{17pt}{18pt}\selectfont\scshape}{\thesection}{15mm}{}
    \titleformat{\subsection}
       {\normalfont\fontsize{16pt}{17pt}\selectfont\scshape}{\thesubsection}{10mm}{}
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}
       {\normalfont\fontsize{15pt}{16pt}\selectfont\scshape}{\thesubsubsection}{10mm}{}
    \titleformat{\paragraph}
       {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{15pt}\selectfont\scshape}{\theparagraph}{10mm}{} 
    \titleformat{\subparagraph}
       {\normalfont\fontsize{13pt}{14pt}\selectfont\scshape}{\thesubparagraph}{10mm}{}
    \begin{document}
    \section{one}
    \lipsum[1]
    \subsection{subone}
    \lipsum[2]
      \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \begin{flushright}
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{flushright}
      \end{figure}
    \section{two}
    \lipsum[3]
    \subsection{subtwo}
      \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \begin{flushright}
          \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftskip\relax]{example-image}
        \end{flushright}
      \end{figure}
    \lipsum[4]
    \end{document}
```

[image: what im looking for]

Comment: you should never directly access `\leftskip` in a latex document, are you looking for `\linewidth` ? however `\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftskip\relax` probably works

Comment: I know my need is somekind special and not covered by article. Anyway: `\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftskip\relax` does not work.

Comment: if they don't work then `\leftskip` presumably doesn't have the value that you expect at the point it is evaluated. It is hard to guess what is happening as you have shown no code. Every question really needs a complete small test file that allows the code to be debugged (you can use `example-image` as the image as that is available for such tests

Comment: i added a MWE. Duno if its relevant that i use the \leftskip to get my textfields shifted right below the section number...

Comment: as I say, setting `\leftskip` directly is always wrong, latex assumes that `\@totalleftmargin`, \lineskip`, \textwidth` and `\hsize` are in correct relationship and if you set one without resetting the others to match, things will break.

Comment: do you have a solution to indent the text below a section as in the image i added now with correct relationships?

Comment: do you really want parindent and parskip both 0 (how can you see the start of a paragraph?)

Answer (score 3):

The expression `\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftskip` works, however `\leftskip` inside `flushright` is `0.0pt plus 1.0fil` so acts as `0pt` in a `\dimexpr` so the value is `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[
    left=20mm,
    right=20mm,
    top=20mm,
    bottom=18mm,
    footskip=2em,
    headheight=2em,
    headsep=0.8em
    ]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}   
    \usepackage{lipsum} 

    \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip} % this is not used     
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}             
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}% really?
      \setlength{\textwidth}{483pt}

    \addtolength\oddsidemargin{60pt}       
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\section}
       {\normalfont\fontsize{17pt}{18pt}\selectfont\scshape}{\hspace*{-\oddsidemargin}\rlap{\thesection}}{\oddsidemargin}{}
    \titleformat{\subsection}
       {\normalfont\fontsize{16pt}{17pt}\selectfont\scshape}{\hspace*{-\oddsidemargin}\rlap{\thesubsection}}{\oddsidemargin}{}
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}
       {\normalfont\fontsize{15pt}{16pt}\selectfont\scshape}{\thesubsubsection}{10mm}{}
    \titleformat{\paragraph}
       {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{15pt}\selectfont\scshape}{\theparagraph}{10mm}{} 
    \titleformat{\subparagraph}
       {\normalfont\fontsize{13pt}{14pt}\selectfont\scshape}{\thesubparagraph}{10mm}{}
    \begin{document}
    \section{one}
    \lipsum[1]
    \subsection{subone}
    \lipsum[2]


          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

    \section{two}
    \lipsum[3]
    \subsection{subtwo}
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

    \lipsum[4]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: ok so im asking for the wrong thing. I am looking for the now added redline in the new image. How can i get the image only that wide?

Comment: the length if the current textblock is `\linewidth` so you should be using that but also it should not be inside `figure`. The  whole point of `figure` is that it is a float that will not appear in place inside the indented region so it normalises to document width and forgets the current indentation. If you use `\includegraphics` directly it would be positioned just as a letter is positioned , and fall naturally at the left margin. @novski

Comment: @novski I added a suggested version (although really that is unrelated to the original question about arithmetic in width=)

Comment: you probably want to reduce `\textwidth` by 60pt in my version to match the increas in oddsidemargin

Comment: I copied the original code here but it doesn't make a lot of sense to load `geometry` to set the page size and margins in a consistent way, then change settings such as `\textwidth`  "by hand" just set the page format you want using `geometry`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle--whoo this helped--i was getting output of \textwidth-.93em as just .93 but adding \dimexpr-\textwidth-.93em gave me the result  -- taken from   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312522/197451

Comment: @jsbibra it is hard to imagine any case when you should be subtracting .93em from `\textwidth` !!!